# Where can I read about this 'rule'?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was trying to solve an equation, I got nowhere, and the solution used a 'rule' that I have never seen before, $a^TX\,b = b^TX\,a$.

What is this rule?
Where can I read about it?

Note: $a$ and $b$ are vectors and $X$ is a matrix.

Comment: If $c$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix, then $c^T=c$. Set $c=a^TXb$. Then $(a^TXb)^T=b^T X^T (a^T)^T=b^TX^Ta$.

Comment: This is a special case of the rule for the transpose of a product of matrices: $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$ (and so, $(ABC)^T = C^T B^T A^T$, etc).

Answer (score 4):

I guess, $X$ is *symmetric* here, because in general, the following holds:
$$a^TXb= b^TX^Ta$$

which is a simple application of $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$ and the fact that the scalars as $1\times 1$ matrices are all 'symmetric': $\lambda=\lambda^T$.

More specifically:
$$a^TXb = (a^TXb)^T=b^TX^Ta$$

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing here is the fact that $a^TXb$ is simply just a complex number. I think your problem is missing some context, but usually an inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is defined by a symmetric positive definite matrix (let's call it $X$).  In this case we have that $\langle a, b \rangle = a^TXb$.  Noting however that the inner product takes two vectors and gives us a number, and the fact that the inner product is symmetric tells us that $\langle a, b \rangle = \langle b, a \rangle$ and therefore $a^TXb = b^TXa$.

Answer (score 0):

a^t is for transpose, right?

$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a_1 & a_2  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        x_{11} & x_{12}  \\
        x_{21} & x_{22} \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        b_1 \\ b_2  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$ = $a_1b_1x_{11} + a_2b_1x_{21} + a_1b_2x_{12} + a_2b_2x_{22} $

but

$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        b_1 & b_2  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        x_{11} & x_{12}  \\
        x_{21} & x_{22} \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a_1 \\ a_2  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$ = $a_1b_1x_{11} + a_1b_2x_{21} + a_2b_1x_{12} + a_2b_2x_{22} $

So, if X is symmetrical, ($x_{12} = x_{21}$), then this rule is true just by doing multiplication.